# Given this Worker-API, how do I create an infinite loop of Jobs?

Tags: multithreading, go, design-patterns, api-design

Since I wasn't able to find anything about my specific problem, I'm going to ask this for myself here.

I've got this API for workers in Go:

```
package workerapi
import (...)

var MaxWorkers int = 1 << 16

type Job interface {
    Run()
}

type Pool struct {
    workers  sync.WaitGroup
    jobqueue chan Job
}

func NewPool(n int) (*Pool, error) {
    if n <= 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("worker: number of workers(n=%d) is <= 0", n)
    }
    if n > MaxWorkers {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("worker: number of workers(n=%d) is > MaxWorkers(%d)", n, MaxWorkers)
    }

    p := &Pool{jobqueue: make(chan Job)}

    p.workers.Add(n)
    for i := 1; i <= n; i++ {
        go p.worker()
    }
    return p, nil
}

func (p *Pool) worker() {
    for job := range p.jobqueue {
        job.Run()
    }

    p.workers.Done()
}

func (p *Pool) SubmitAndWait(jobs ...Job) {
    for _, job := range jobs {
        p.jobqueue <- job
    }
    close(p.jobqueue)
    p.workers.Wait()
}
```

My task is now to build an infinite loop of Jobs. This is, what I have so far:

```
package workertest

import (...)

type job struct {
    id int
    // later on, these will contain more data
}

func (j job) Run() {
    sleep := rand.Intn(100)
    fmt.Printf("job %3d: Start   (%dms)\n", j.id, sleep)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(sleep) * time.Millisecond)
    // here some more calculation
    fmt.Printf("job %3d: Stopped (%dms)\n", j.id, sleep)
}

func Start(args []string) {
    nrJobs := len(args)
    const nrWorkers = 5

    fmt.Printf("Starting   %3d workers\n", nrWorkers)
    p, err := workerapi.NewPool(nrWorkers)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Submitting %3d jobs\n", nrJobs)
    jobs := make([]workerapi.Job, nrJobs)
    for i := 0; i < nrJobs; i++ {
        jobs[i] = job{i + 1, args[i]}
    }

    fmt.Println("Submit and Wait ...")
    p.SubmitAndWait(jobs...)
    fmt.Println("Finished all jobs")
}
```

The code above runs every given Job once with 5 workers in total. My goal is to put a finished job into the jobqueue again. But I don't know, how to manage this. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Instead of having everything implemented as methods, I'd have a "worker pool" expose a channel on which you'd submit jobs to it. Then either have the pool to export another channel—for the results, or have each job carry such a channel with it. Then the question of requeueing jobs becomes a matter of shoveling them back to the pool's channel when they get ready. This is actually a pretty standard pattern.

Comment: Can you tell me more precise about this standard pattern? How is it called? I would like to know more about it...

Comment: Sorry, it's not a pattern in the sense of that GoF book, it's in the original meaning of that word ;-)

Comment: [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/nuEHlh_6-GV) is a skeleton implementation of a pool which processes tasks, returns each one back along with the outcome of its execution on the channel submitted by the task (they all use the same channel but this is not a requirement), and the code in the main goroutine puts each completed task back into the pool for re-execution. This all happens until 42 tasks are "round-tripped" this way (to actually have a halt condition for out program).

Comment: In your particular case I see no fit to ever have any special code to "reschedule" tasks as this can be done right by the "worker pool" itself. So basically you shovel tasks into it, it processes each "new" task—as they come it—and then re-posts each completed task back into itself.

Comment: Thank you for the code example. So you mean, that I have to modify the given API to succeed?

Comment: I also notice, that there's only one worker working in the pool, am I right? The newWorkerPool method calls run as a subroutine only once...

Comment: Re. your 2nd question—yes, it actually has a single worker; having `N` workers in the simplest case amounts to executing `go pool.run()` `N` times. This pattern actually has a nifty name: ["fan-out"](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines#TOC_4.). Re. your 1st question—I'm afraid you might be a victim of a common "give me a complete solution" syndrome while you're a programmer and are supposed to actually program. Please read [this](https://whathaveyoutried.com) carefully and try to work on this issue. Have fun!

Comment: Regarding concurrency and the use of channels, please also read [this](https://blog.golang.org/advanced-go-concurrency-patterns) and [this](https://blog.golang.org/go-concurrency-patterns-timing-out-and) and [this](https://blog.golang.org/context) and [this](https://blog.golang.org/index) in general—it's indispensible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think I can move on from here... :-)